# 'hash' tag gives error when clicking on it on SO

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

The lexically first tag '#' gives an error when clicking on it. The url is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/# .  I think it's because SO thinks you search for an anchor. Anyways which that clearly a bug.

The link above works but when you go through https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=name it doesn't (for me).

Edit: The tag has disappeared from the tags page.

Comment: I have retagged that question from (incorrectly) `[#]` to `[c#]`. But the underlying problem still exists though.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%23) takes me to the problemz cat, with error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'AND'.

The same happens for the (non-existing) `[+]`, `[-]` and `[_]` tags; meanwhile, the `[:]` tag gives a blank page, but I think it is a different problem.

Comment: How did you know it was `Incorrect syntax near 'AND'` ? I thought SO wouldn't give up this information. If it did, it'd be like running around and screaming, "We've got an SQL injection hole here!"

Comment: @GSerg - it's an html comment in the source for that page.

Comment: Ah. So they are running around then :)